# SOAP: Different country - different state enum, same webservice interface

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, enums, internationalization

I'm working on a WCF SOAP webservice that allows customers to change an address. Currently we have properties where they can define the country and a state based on some short enums.

The state enum contains at the moment only the Australian states, but now we intend to allow addresses from the US as well, which results in a lot more states than before.
To resolve this I came up with the following three solutions, but none of them seem to be that awesome, any other solutions or at least some pros/cons would be appreciated:

**1. Add US states to the existing enum**

We could just add the extra 50 US states to the existing enum and add some validation when that checks if the selected state belongs to the given country.

**2. Add two new enums to the interface for each country states: AUSStates/USStates**

We could add two new properties to the interface that allows selecting a state for each country (USState & AUSState) and then just select the state based on the given country. We would keep the existing State property so that current users would not have to update their interface.

**3. Add new Interface/Endpoint for the US**

Instead of making the existing interface dirty we could just add a new US interface that offers the US States enum values in the State property. But this would then no longer allow to enter an US address in the AUS interface and the other way round.

We currently don't have any soap versioning and we store the value of the state as a two letter code in the database, no matter what country it belongs to it goes into the same column.

Comment: 4) Make the field a string and let the user put in anything s/he likes. Verify on server side.

Comment: You must use a string for this.  There are actually more "states" for USPS addressing than the 50 legal states, e.g. the District of Columbia, Puerto Rico, various territories like Guam, and armed forces addresses.  Hypothetically, this list could change from year to year.  Current list here: https://www.usps.com/send/official-abbreviations.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nvoigt recommended in the comments I'm going to change it to a string. This results in a interface change which is not nice, but since the xml posted against the service stays the same for an enum or a string most of our integrators do not have an issue with that.